# Ubuntu won't run from USB on only one of 3 machines

Tags: system-installation

I get the screen to choose run from USB. Then the Ubuntu loading screen for about a minute, with mouse active. Then my monitor goes to sleep, means no signal. I'm using "universal-USB-Installer-1.9.3.9.exe" and "Ubuntu-12.04.2-desktop-i386.iso".  The USB is an 8 gb Kingston and on a desktop system with the same motherboard, both 32 bit, works fine. Also works on my wife's laptop. Mine has XP, theirs have 7. What don't I know?

Comment: If you have UEFI you need the 64-bit version, not the i386. Try again with that.

Answer (score 0):

I think it because that your computer can't detect the format.You can try to format it as USB-HDD or USB-ZIP. I have installed the Ubuntu 13.04 on the Dell Latitude D520 successfully.

Comment: It recognizes the stick and starts. Just doesn't finish. I now see that my 32 bit machine has a UEFI bios, so may need a different version.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, You have to boot your USB in Fat32 before installing Linux. In this case I would suggest you to boot again in USB with Unetbootin, you will get 100% success :)

Comment: I formatted the stick with the installer before while installing. And it works on an identical computer beside me. t recognizes the stick and starts. Just doesn't finish. I now see that my 32 bit machine has a UEFI bios, so may need a different version.